# Elixir's Kernel.SpecialForms.case/2: multi clauses "head" to execute the same "body"

Tags: elixir

I have a simple question about `case` statement in Elixir (`Kernel.SpecialForms.case/2` to be precise: [GitHub](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/lib/kernel/special_forms.ex#L1470), [The awesome pretty doc](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/master/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#case/2)). Sometimes, I want several clauses/pattern matching to execute the same thing. I always find a solution with *guards* to fake it, but I would like to know if it's possible to define several pattern matching to execute the same block of code.

In Ruby for example (I don't use `case` in Ruby, it's just an illustration), you can apparently do something like this:

```
case condition
  when clause1, clause2
    value1
  when clause3
    value3
end
```

In Elixir, to avoid something like this:

```
case [a, b] do
 [_, 0] -> a + b
 [_, 1] -> a + b
 [_, 2] -> a + b
 [_, _] -> 10 * b + a
end
```

I maybe do something like this (that's totally fine BTW):

```
case [a, b] do
 [_, b] when b >= 0 and b <= 2 -> a + b
 [_, _] -> 10 * b + a
end
```

What I'm asking is if there's a way to do:

```
case condition
  clause1, clause2 -> puts "do something"
  clause3 -> puts "do something else"
end
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way. :) You can move the shared code to a function though and call it from each clause body.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give an example of what @Jose is saying:

```
defmodule Sharedcalls do
    def is_one(a=1,b), do: a_and_b_func
    def is_one(a, b=1), do: a_and_b_func
    def is_one(a, b), do: some_other_func
    defp a_and_b_func, do: IO.puts("a_and_b_func")
    defp some_other_func, do: IO.puts("Neither input is one")
end

Sharedcalls.is_one(1,0)
Sharedcalls.is_one(0,1)
Sharedcalls.is_one(0,0)
```

Just in case anyone is unclear on what he meant in his answer. I realize that's not exactly parallel to your example above but I think it's enough for someone to figure it out.